# How to calculate the tilt angle of a pin inside a clearance hole

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let's assume a hole of diameter 100mm in a 50 mm thick plate and a pin of diameter 98 mm and length 200 mm (longer than the hole depth). Is there a way calculate the max tilt angle of the pin inside hole?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider the diagonal line between the two points of contact.
Its angle relative to the vertical is $\tan^{-1} \frac{100}{50}$, and its length is $L=\sqrt{100^2+50^2}$.
If you straighten up the pin as in the first picture, that line between the pin's contact points has an angle from the vertical of $\sin^{-1}\frac{98}{L}$.

The difference of those two angles is how much the pin has tilted.

Note that the picture is not at all to scale, as the $50$ looks much longer than the $100$.

Answer (score 0):

The image below illustrates how to find the tilt angle.

From the top right point of contact, draw the red line perpendicular to the axis of the pin.  And draw the green line horizontally till it meets it the other edge of the pin.

The angle between the red line and green line is the tilt angle $\theta$

The length of the red line is $98$.  Therefore, the length of the green line is

$\dfrac{98}{\cos \theta} $

So that on the left, the gap between the pin and and the hole edge is

$ G = 100 - \dfrac{98}{\cos \theta} $

Therefore,

$ \tan \theta = \dfrac{ 100 - \dfrac{98}{\cos \theta} }{50} $

i.e.

$ 50 \tan \theta = 100 - \dfrac{98}{\cos \theta} $

Multiply through by $ \cos \theta $

$ 50 \sin \theta = 100 \cos \theta - 98 $

And finally we get

$ 100 \cos \theta - 50 \sin \theta = 98 $

The solution of this trigonometric equation is

$ \theta = - \tan^{-1} \dfrac{50}{100} + \cos^{-1} \dfrac{98}{\sqrt{100^2 + 50^2}} $

And this evaluates to

$ \theta = 2.207348^\circ $

[image]